# installing pear package gives "could not download" message

Tags: download, pear, vps

I am setting up a Ubuntu (the problem also happens on Debian Squeeze) Virtual Private Server. I have installed php5 and php-pear. When I go to install a pear package from the command, or if I attempt to upgrade packages, for example

```
# sudo pear upgrade-all
```

pear always gets a "could not download" message. The command above gave:

Could not download from "http://pear.php.net/get/Structures_Graph-1.0.4.tgz", cannot download

> "pear/structures_graph" (File
>   http://pear.php.net:80/get/Structures_Graph-1.0.4.tgz not valid
>   (redirected but no location)) Error: cannot download
>   "pear/Structures_Graph"

I tried purge php-pear and reinstalling. I tried Debian instead of Ubuntu, but got the same message.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you're behind a proxy?

Try to find out what's happening:

```
 $ curl -I  http://pear.php.net:80/get/Structures_Graph-1.0.4.tgz
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 ...
```

The error you got indicates that you don't get a "200 OK" but something different, which is probably injected by your firewall, proxy or so. Fix that.